# Postfix and google apps email limit

Tags: email, postfix, g-suite

I installed postfix on my ubuntu vps. The server is hosting mysite.com.

I set the MX records for mysite.com to use google apps for email:
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM ...

I am using php's mail() function, and emails are working. Google apps has a 500 email / day limit. Am I using this limit? I'm not sure what postfix is doing exactly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your own /var/log/mail.info logs to get a count of how many messages your vps has sent.

Your lack of information, however, suggests that postfix is delivering the message itself, independent of Google's servers.  IIRC, Google will only permit relaying if you use a username + password to connect to their outbound SMTP server.  Unless you tweaked postfix to use google as a smarthost, with ssl, with your username and password, your vps is probably handling delivery all by it self. (which means no daily limit applies)

Comment: Thanks, I just tested and sent out 600 emails! You were right.